# Part of an unit circle $e^{iz}$, where $\Re(z) \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a unit circle $e^{iz}$ . Let's think about such $z \in C$, that $\Re(z) \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Which part of my unit circle is this? How to find the answer? I know that $z$ is the angle measure, don't know if it's gonna help. And also that every point of this circle can be parametrized by (cos(z), sin(z)). But I don't know how to use those facts. Can you help?

Comment: $e^{iz}$ represents the unit circle (or part of it) if $z$ is real, so taking the real part of $z$ seems to be a misunderstanding. Do you know $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$?

Comment: My guess is that the question is asking what part of the complex plane will such points cover. In that case recommend looking at $e^{i(\Re z + i\Im z)}$ instead.